The meaning of "yourself" in "Getting ahead of yourself."
Earlier, I needed to make a sentence like this:

For dating, it's important not to get ahead of yourself.

This made me question what "yourself" here is indicating. This expression means, "You shouldn't outpace how your dating partner thinks of you." Then isn't it supposed to be "getting ahead of your dating partner" because the listener is supposedly going beyond their partner's expectation, not themselves? If this is not the case, what is "yourself" this listener is getting ahead of?

To get ahead of oneself is a quirky idiomatic usage that can't really be deconstructed. Compare fall over oneself (To expend a lot of energy or effort to do something; to inconvenience oneself). In both cases the peculiar "reflexive" aspect adds a kind of emphasis, but you'll get nowhere trying to assign "meaning" to the reflexive pronoun itself. Just accept that to get ahead of yourself means to proceed too quickly (often, with insufficient attention to essential details).

In your exact context, the real underlying implication is probably more don't go too fast for your dating partner rather than ...for yourself, but that's just a quirk of the exact context. Normally, getting ahead of yourself doesn't imply being precipitate / over-hasty from the perspective of others.

@FumbleFingers - I tend to interpret (or intend) getting ahead of yourself (or ourselves) to mean proceeding further along some line of thought or some plan than is justified by the current state of affairs, so that in the context of the question, planning a wedding after one date (or booking a motel room!) might qualify as getting ahead of yourself.

@MichaelHarvey: Well, obviously in OP's exact context there's the strong implication you're moving ahead too quickly for your prospective wife  if you're booking the honeymoon suite before you've even paid the restaurant bill for your initial blind date! But you could be getting ahead of yourself if you're dreaming of writing a computer program to solve world hunger, having just bought an old copy of The Idiot's Guide to Computer Programming. And in that context, there's no implication of going too fast for someone else to keep up!

I note that there are a number of 'physically impossible' idioms involving oneself, e.g. getting ahead of yourself (as discussed), getting above yourself (seeming to have excessively entitled or snobbish ideas or manners), being beside yourself (being very agitated or upset). The 'impossibility' serves as emphasis.

@MichaelHarvey: That's it! I said adds a kind of emphasis in my first comment, but I didn't really have a clear idea of how / why it does that. Now I understand it as calling attention to the mismatch between reality (represented by you yourself) and your actions / appearance / aspirations. Basically, there's something impossible / inappropriate / unreal about the relationship between an actual person himself, and his situation or perspective.

@FumbleFingers - if someone seems 'bumptious' (irritatingly self-assertive), we can say that they are full of himself (or herself) which doesn't seem quite like the previous ones, and neither does saying she married beneath herself. Not exactly.

Let's not forget how an annoyingly self-assured, smug,  arrogant, self-important or self-satisfied.person may seem to be up himself (or herself) (up his or her own ass/arse). UK, Australia, New Zealand.

Well, although some of my comments are addressed to you, I'm not trying to teach you anything. They're for the benefit  of learners who might be thinking Short of remembering each different context for this reflexive usage according to its dictionary definition, is there any useful principle that applies to at least some of them? It doesn't really help if we present them with a bewildering array of idiomatic usages that have little connection beyond the reflexive pronoun (itself! :)

@FumbleFingers - I wasn't implying anything by mentioning people being up themselves!

It doesn't mean "you shouldn't outpace how your dating partner thinks of you".  It means don't rush headlong into a situation before you're prepared for it and things are as they need to be, whatever the situation happens to be.
You could start painting a house before you've cleaned and prepared the surfaces that need painting.  Someone experienced in housepainting could advise you, "Don't get ahead of yourself. You need to scrape off the old loose paint first, and sand any rough spots."
So sometimes being prepared for the situation involves making sure that all "parties" involved (here, that's you and the house) are ready. You've got your paintbrush and paint, your eye-protection and gloves, and it's only when the house has been readied for painting that you should begin painting, otherwise you're getting ahead of yourself.
